# Setting constraints on contentView edges breaks layout of UITableViewCell with masonry

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, masonry

I'm trying to create a tableview cell with an image on the left, and a content box on the right.  The image should be square and 20% of the width of the cell, and the content box (`background` in the code below) should be at least as large as the image.  Finally, I would like to respect the layout margins of the tableview itself.

This is working well except for the last step, respect table view's margins.  Setting this results in my content box getting set too large or too small when the tableview is wide.

```
// Base class
    [self.background setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];

    [self.background mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(8.0).with.priorityMedium();
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(-8.0).with.priorityMedium();
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(4.0);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(-4.0);
    }];

    // **** This block results in respecting tableview margins, but height constraints of background are not respected.  Comment it out to create image "B".
    [self.contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.mas_leadingMargin);
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.mas_trailingMargin);
        make.top.equalTo(self.mas_top).with.priorityHigh();
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.mas_bottom).with.priorityHigh();
    }];
    // **** End problematic block

// Subclass
    [self.courseImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(8.0);
        make.height.and.width.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_width).multipliedBy(.20).with.priorityHigh();
        make.centerY.equalTo(contentView);
    }];
    [self.background mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.courseImageView.mas_trailing).with.offset(8.0);
        make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(self.courseImageView).with.priorityMedium();
        make.height.equalTo(self.courseImageView).with.priorityLow();
    }];
```

A.) Here, the content box's height is correct, but margins are not respected
[image: Here, the content box's height is correct, but margins are not respected]

B.) And here, the margins are respected, but the `background` has been expanded to a ridiculous amount.  Also, the the tableview appears scrolled up when it reloads like this.
[image: And here, the margins are respected, but the <code>background</code> has been expanded to a ridiculous amount.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the code was of course doing exactly what I told it to do.  The above code set the heights (greater than or) equal to 20% of the width of the table view cell.  However this was ignoring the layout margins when setting the heights, leading to the strange behavior.

In addition to this, I do not believe that it's correct/necessary to add constraints on contentView in the parent class.  Simply adding the `availableWidth` view fixed my problem on iPad, but on iPhone the layout broke again.  In order for both platforms to layout properly I had to change my base class constraints as below.

Here's my updated code:

```
// Base Class
    [self.background mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_leadingMargin).with.priorityMedium();
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_trailingMargin).with.priorityMedium();
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_top).with.offset(4.0);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).with.offset(-4.0);
    }];
// *** Constraints on self.contentView are not necessary to respect the default margins! ***

// Subclass
    ...
    UIView *availableWidth = [UIView new];
    availableWidth.hidden = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:availableWidth];

    [self.courseImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_leadingMargin);
        make.height.and.width.equalTo(availableWidth.mas_width).multipliedBy(.20);
        make.centerY.equalTo(contentView);
    }];
    [self.background mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.courseImageView.mas_trailing).with.offset(8.0);
        make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(availableWidth.mas_width).multipliedBy(.20).with.priorityHigh();
    }];
    [availableWidth mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_leadingMargin);
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_trailingMargin);
        make.height.equalTo(@0);
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what's the priority applied by default by Masonry. Their documentation doesn't clearly speak about this.

[Masonry - Learn to Priortize](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry#learn-to-prioritize)

#### STEP #1

Try to set high priority for `leading / trailing` inside the problematic block-

```
// **** This block results in respecting tableview margins, but height constraints of background are not respected.  Comment it out to create image "B".
    [self.contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.equalTo(self.mas_leadingMargin).with.priorityHigh();
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.mas_trailingMargin).with.priorityHigh();
        make.top.equalTo(self.mas_top).with.priorityHigh();
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.mas_bottom).with.priorityHigh();
    }];
    // **** End problematic block
```

#### STEP #2

Try to set `backgroundColor` on `cell.contentView` to see how far it stretches in your cases A & B. That'll give you a better idea.

#### STEP #3 (Not Recommended Approach, Worst Case Scenario)

Nothing works out.

- Reset `leading/trailing` parts `layoutMargins` for table to `0`.
- Add a new `wrapperView` inside `cell.contentView` in your subclass and set it's `leading/trailing` to expected values.
- If you don't want to add a `wrapperView`, use the expected `leading/trailing` value as direct value for `leading/trailing` for all the components inside `cell.contentView`.

Ultimately it depends no your choice how far you want to chase this if this doesn't work out like expected. I have had to settle at #3 sometimes. Hope it helps.

Comment: Tarun, thanks for your answer.  I didn't end up actually using any of your suggestions directly, but just thinking about what *would* happen if I changed the contentView background color made me realize that I was ignoring the layout margins in the height code.  So I've accepted my own answer, but the bounty is yours for getting me started in the right direction.